# How to display shrepoint list with folders using xslt

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010

I have custom list which i need to display in webPartPage using XSLT. I create view, where just one field `Title` and set `scope="recursive"`, but on the page displays only the folder title.

```
<View BaseViewID="2" Type="HTML" TabularView="FALSE" Scope="Recursive">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">10</RowLimit>
  </View>
```

i have feature that link it

```
<File Path="MainPage/default.aspx" Url="default.aspx">
      <View WebPartOrder="1" WebPartZoneID="Main" BaseViewID="2" List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/RequestList">
        <![CDATA[
              <webParts>
                  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
                      <metaData>
                          <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                          <importErrorMessage>Невозможно импортировать эту веб-часть.</importErrorMessage>
                      </metaData>
                      <data>
                          <properties>
                              <property name="InitialAsyncDataFetch" type="bool">False</property>
                              <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">Default</property>
                              <property name="Title" type="string" />
                              <property name="Height" type="string" />
                              <property name="CacheXslStorage" type="bool">True</property>
                              <property name="ListDisplayName" type="string" />
                              <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
                              <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
                              <property name="XmlDefinitionLink" type="string" />
                              <property name="DataFields" type="string" />
                              <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
                              <property name="ListName" type="string">{39C129CE-1800-48EB-A8ED-1C304C1FE457}</property>
                              <property name="NoDefaultStyle" type="string" null="true" />
                              <property name="AutoRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
                              <property name="ViewFlag" type="string">8388621</property>
                              <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
                              <property name="AutoRefreshInterval" type="int">60</property>
                              <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
                              <property name="Description" type="string" />
                              <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
                              <property name="ShowWithSampleData" type="bool">False</property>
                              <property name="ParameterBindings" type="string">
                                  &lt;ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/&gt;
                                  &lt;ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/&gt;
                                  &lt;ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/&gt;
                                  &lt;ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/&gt;
                                  &lt;ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" /&gt;
                                  &lt;ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" /&gt;
                                  &lt;ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" /&gt;
                                  &lt;ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" /&gt;
                                  &lt;ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" /&gt;
                                  &lt;ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" /&gt;
                              </property>
                              <property name="Xsl" type="string" null="true" />
                              <property name="CacheXslTimeOut" type="int">86400</property>
                              <property name="WebId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</property>
                              <property name="ListUrl" type="string" />
                              <property name="DataSourceID" type="string" />
                              <property name="FireInitialRow" type="bool">True</property>
                              <property name="ManualRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
                              <property name="ViewFlags" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewFlags, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Html, TabularView, Hidden, Mobile</property>
                              <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
                              <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
                              <property name="PageSize" type="int">-1</property>
                              <property name="SampleData" type="string" null="true" />
                              <property name="BaseXsltHashKey" type="string" null="true" />
                              <property name="AsyncRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
                              <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Modeless</property>
                              <property name="ListId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">39c129ce-1800-48eb-a8ed-1c304c1fe457</property>
                              <property name="DataSourceMode" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceMode, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">List</property>
                              <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
                              <property name="TitleUrl" type="string">default.aspx</property>
                              <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string">/_layouts/images/itgen.png</property>
                              <property name="DataSourcesString" type="string" />
                              <property name="GhostedXslLink" type="string">main.xsl</property>
                              <property name="PageType" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.PAGETYPE, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">PAGE_NORMALVIEW</property>
                              <property name="DisplayName" type="string" />
                              <property name="UseSQLDataSourcePaging" type="bool">True</property>
                              <property name="Width" type="string" />
                              <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
                              <property name="XslLink" type="string">/_layouts/[]/xsl/archive.xsl</property>
                              <property name="ViewContentTypeId" type="string">0x</property>
                              <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
                              <property name="XmlDefinition" type="string" />
                              <property name="Default" type="string" />
                              <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
                              <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Невозможно импортировать эту веб-часть.</property>
                              <property name="SelectParameters" type="string" />
                          </properties>
                      </data>
                  </webPart>
              </webParts>
              ]]>
      </View>
    </File>
```

and simple xsl like there 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604024(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Not all of the people familiar with XSLT are familiar with the SharePoint document and list XML format. It would be helpful if you could post a short example of the XML in order to demonstrate what the XML looks like and to see how to achieve what you want and provide you with an answer.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could post the XSLT that is currently being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Scope="Recursive" into second View (where you define WebPartZone and etc.)

Let's try:

```
<File Path="MainPage/default.aspx" Url="default.aspx">
  <View WebPartOrder="1" WebPartZoneID="Main" BaseViewID="2" List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/RequestList" Scope="Recursive">
```

...